# Can i use Mongo NoSQL Database with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to use NOSQL database for my mobile application back end web services. I have gone through the MongoDB document.But i am not sure will it be suitable with PHP?
And I have below queries related to the same.

1. Can i use Mysql and NoSQL(MongoDB) databases on the same server?
2. Can i use MongoDB with PHP and apache? If yes then which version of MongoDB should i use for PHP?
3. Is it possible to install NoSQL database if LAMP is already installed on the same machine?

Regards,
Pratibha

Comment: Have you tried putting the same queries into **Google**?

Comment: answer of your all three questions are "YES"

Answer (score 1):

In following lines few short answer:

1. Yes. You should only install PHP Mongodb driver for your PHP version. The MongoDB PHP driver should work on nearly any system: Windows, Mac OS X, Unix, and Linux; little- and big-endian machines; 32- and 64-bit machines; PHP 5.2, 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5.
2. Yes. Latest version should be the best choice.
3. Yes. As far as I know Mongodb server relies on different ports and in standard condition there is no conflict.

Your server should have only enough resources (basically enough memory) to run everything.